# How to turn a sequence into a series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

From archimedes formula for $\pi$ I got this series

$$\pi = \lim _{n\to \infty} 2n \sqrt{2-\sqrt{4-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{4-...}}}}$$

Now I can't find the general member formula for this sequence to even check if it's correct using symbolab or something.

Is there a trick to find the general member formula of this sequence or turn this sequence into an infinite series?

And given some infinite series how to turn it into yet another one with the same converging value.

For example how to ultimately get to Leibniz formula for $\frac\pi4=1-\frac13+\frac15+...$

Comment: You can typeset formulae by surrounding $\LaTeX$ code with dollar signs. I have edited the question for you, and it will be displayed once approved by trusted members of the site. Please tell me if my edit reflects your original question.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know if my sequence is exactly right, your Latex translation certainly isn't, there should be minus sines instead of multiplication.

Comment: Now I fit up...

Comment: @Ezio The infinite-radical is not correct. I've given a corrected version of it as a comment in your previous question.
Check out this to know why the identity is true. This paper derives the relation geometrically: http://mypages.iit.edu/~maslanka/Math122notes1.pdf

Comment: @Ezio also there is no direct relation between the Archimedes identity and Leibniz's series. Leibniz's series comes from the series for $\arctan(x)$. i.e: $$\arctan\left(x\right)=x-\frac{x^{3}}{3}+\frac{x^{5}}{5}-\frac{x^{7}}{7}+...$$ If we put $x=1$, we get Leibniz's series.

Comment: Be that as it may, I still would like a derivation of some series that converges to pi directly from the archimedes calculation, without taking a trigonometry roundabout that is. Can this infinite radical be plugged into symbol ab to compute pi?

Comment: Can I turn this infinite radical directly into an infinite fraction, then I at least have partial fractions to dedude convergence